# Significance test between Overlapped data in excel

Tags: statistics

Below is the brand preference metric data for two overlapped time periods (Week 1-3 and Week 2-4 data). I wanted do a significance test between these two overlapped groups, please provide me the details of the method and formula’s to use. We are doing these activities in excel format.

Here is the my data :

```
                   Roll Up Week 1-3  Roll Up Week 2-4  
Count                  697               706
Brand Preference       43%               40%
```

Thanks,
Tanuvi

Comment: You'll need to define exactly what you mean by "significance test"

Comment: @TimWilliams, Here we are trying to understand the likelihood that a relationship between two or more variables is caused by something other than random chance (nothing but Statistical hypothesis at confidence level 90%)

Comment: This question seems to be a question about statistics, not programming.

Comment: @TimWilliams, Yes